# How to merge below array in PHP?

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two json format where I am converting that json into  array and then merge it, but its not working.

see below two json format.

Below is my code in PHP and its not merging the array, what wrongs here ?

```
$arr1 = json_decode('{
   "PatchDeployment":[
      {
         "ehubid":"123",
         "tomcats":[
           
            {
               "tomcatname":"mytomcat",
               "servername":"myserver",
               "serverip":"xx.xx.xx.xxx",
               "tomcat_statuses":{
                  "stoptomcat":"Success"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}', true);


$arr2 = json_decode('{
   "PatchDeployment":[
      {
         "ehubid":"123",
         "tomcats":[
            {
               "tomcatname":"mytomcat",
               "servername":"myserver",
               "serverip":"xx.xx.xx.xxx",
               "tomcat_statuses":{
                  "checkdb":"Failed",
                  "checkhub":"couldnt connect to host"
               }
            }
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}', true);


$mergedarray = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

I want array should be like below after merging $mergedarray:

```
Array
(
    [PatchDeployment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ehubid] => 123
                    [tomcats] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tomcatname] => mytomcat
                                    [servername] => myserver
                                    [serverip] => xx.xx.xx.xxx
                                    [tomcat_statuses] => Array
                                        (
                                            [checkdb] => Failed
                                            [checkhub] => couldnt connect to host
                                            [stoptomcat]=> Success
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am merging two array into php

Anyone can help me to sort out this issue as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want them to repeat. The method you are looking for: `array_replace_recursive`

**Code**

```
$arr1 = json_decode('{
    "PatchDeployment":[
        {
            "ehubid":"123",
            "tomcats":[

                {
                "tomcatname":"mytomcat",
                "servername":"myserver",
                "serverip":"xx.xx.xx.xxx",
                "tomcat_statuses":{
                    "stoptomcat":"Success"
                }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}', true);

$arr2 = json_decode('{
    "PatchDeployment":[
        {
            "ehubid":"123",
            "tomcats":[
                {
                "tomcatname":"mytomcat",
                "servername":"myserver",
                "serverip":"xx.xx.xx.xxx",
                "tomcat_statuses":{
                    "checkdb":"Failed",
                    "checkhub":"couldnt connect to host"
                }
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}', true);

$mergedarray = array_replace_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
print '<pre>';
print_r($mergedarray);
print '</pre>';
exit;
```

*Result*

```
Array
(
    [PatchDeployment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ehubid] => 123
                    [tomcats] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [tomcatname] => mytomcat
                                    [servername] => myserver
                                    [serverip] => xx.xx.xx.xxx
                                    [tomcat_statuses] => Array
                                        (
                                            [stoptomcat] => Success
                                            [checkdb] => Failed
                                            [checkhub] => couldnt connect to host
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `array_merge_recursive`:

```
$mergedArr = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```